# Can't get back button work correctly in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Can't get back button work correctly in this example. Always returning to database state.

```js
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true,
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
      redirectsTo: 'databases'
    })
  }),
  databases: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/databases',
    show: Ember.Route.transitionTo('database'),
    connectOutlets: function(router) {
      var applicationController = router.get('applicationController');
      applicationController.connectOutlet('databases');
      App.router.get('databasesController').loadDatabases();
    }
  }),
  database: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: "/databases/:db_name",
    connectOutlets: function(router, db) {
      var applicationController = router.get('applicationController');
      applicationController.connectOutlet('database', db);
    }
  })
})
```

Link to action 'show': `{{ action show db href=true }}`

```
STATEMANAGER: Entering root ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min.js:18
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'navigateAway' to state root. ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min.js:18
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'unroutePath' to state root. ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min.js:18
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'routePath' to state root. ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min.js:18
STATEMANAGER: Entering root.index ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min.js:18
STATEMANAGER: Entering databases
```

Then I am clicking a 'show' action

```
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'show' to state databases. ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min.js:18
STATEMANAGER: Entering database
```

Now pressing browser's back button

```
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'navigateAway' to state database. ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min.js:18
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'unroutePath' to state database. ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min.js:18
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'routePath' to state database.
```

Why it's state database? I guess it's because of `transitionTo('database')` in show action. What is the golden path to successfully display a list of items, click one and get detailed view, than click "back' and return to list view?

Comment: Sammy, I would start by nesting the `databases` and `database` routes inside the `root` route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to  Mehul Kar's comment, routes should be nested.

Comment: Haha, I didn't think that was the answer, but glad to know it solved the issue.